# Textwrapping within Textblock within Togglebutton within ListBox ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout

I'm trying to achieve a ToggleButton control template for listbox items. This is to be used in an application where the user can click on the listbox items to show a certain piece of functionality.

The listbox item template is defined as follows:

```
    <Style x:Key="ExampleListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"
                                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="ExampleTitle" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="#333333" 
                                       FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Fonts/#Neuropol Regular" 
                                       FontSize="16" Height="26" TextAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                       VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding ExampleDisplayName}"
                                       Margin="5"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Foreground="#333333" Margin="5,-5,5,3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                       TextAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Verdana" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ExampleDescription}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ToggleButton>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

and the listbox is defined as

```
        <ListBox x:Name="_examplesListBox" 
                 SelectionMode="Single"
                 BorderBrush="Transparent"
                 Background="Transparent"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding AllExamples}" 
                 ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ExampleListBoxItemStyle}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedExample, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Here I have two textblocks, one bound to ExampleDisplayName, the other bound to ExampleDescription. The effect I am trying to achieve is to get the second textblock (description) to wrap around, constrained by the available space.

This is what I'm getting now:

[image: SciChart Beta Examples Listbox Styling]

What I'd like is for the second line showing example description to wrap based on the size of the listbox. When the application starts the listbox should auto-size to the first line + margin.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Removing that horizontal scrollbar should help with text wrapping:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
```

I'm not quite sure how to auto-size `ListBox` on startup based on first text line size using only XAML.

Comment: Boom! One line fix. TextBlocks with text wrapping basically stretch to fit the parent. The first line is requesting a certain size so just turning off the listbox horizontal scrollbar forced it to size and wrap correctly. Thanks!