# ListBoxItem HorizontalContentAlignment To Stretch Across Full Width of ListBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox, listboxitem

I have a problem with my `ListBoxItem`'s on a Windows Phone 8 app, while trying to get them to stretch across all the width of the `ListBox`.

My `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Events}" 
      behaviors:ItemClickCommandBehavior.Command="{Binding EventSelectedCommand}"
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EventListTemplateSelector}"/>
```

And its DataTemplates are in a seperate xaml resource file:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="EventListHeaderTemplate">
    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid Height="50">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding ImageUri}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="30"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding SomeText}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="Black"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

I cant get the items to really Stretch, and I dont know where the problem is. I have tried to set the `ItemContainerStyle` HorizontalCOntentAlignment="Stretch" and it didn't work. I have tried many other combinations and it seems that only setting the Border or Grid width to a constant works and one other solution that works is to set the Border width to bind to the ActualWidth of the containing ListBox, but I want to use the Stretch variant if could make it work.

Comment: Check this Q: [How to get a ListBox ItemTemplate to stretch horizontally the full width of the ListBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838828/how-to-get-a-listbox-itemtemplate-to-stretch-horizontally-the-full-width-of-the)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I ran into the same in XAML and it drove me nuts wondering why my `TextBlock` was not fully colored across the width.

The way to work with the competing styles (**this works for any of the xaml variants actually**) is to define style of the `ListBoxItem` explicitly to handle the space usage.

That gives the xaml a hint that it is to fill in (*stretch*) to the screen area in this way:

```
    <ListBox Name="lbTest" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  >

        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                        Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>...</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Otherwise the xaml parser, by default, tries to conserve space by *auto* sizing it to the contents of the `ListBoxItem`; giving it that dreaded scotch tape look.

Comment: Is this a bug made by Microsoft? I have wasted three hours until I have found your post. Thank you.

Comment: It is simply a chain of default styles which in stand alone controls make sense, but when brought together give us this.... Welcome to the club who found this style Easter Egg. ;-)