# ListBox internal layout

Tags: wpf, layout, listbox, listboxitem

My WPF application has a `ListBox` whose `ItemTemplate` looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DomainTemplate" DataType="DomainViewModel">
    <Border BorderBrush="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BrushConverter}, Path=IsSelected}"
            BorderThickness="3"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Name="SelectedBorder"
            Padding="5">
        <Button Click="SelectDomain_Click"
                FontSize="16"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                IsEnabled="{Binding Path=CurrentSiteIsValid, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type c:DomainPicker}}}"
                MinHeight="60"
                Tag="{Binding Path=DomainId}"
                Width="120">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                       TextAlignment="Center"
                       TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" />
        </Button>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

The window's width is driven by the width of the `ListBox`.  This is by design.  There seems to a very large space between the vertical edges of the `ListBox` and the items in it.  Using Snoop, I see that the `ListBoxItem` contains a `Border` that is the same width as the `ListBox`, has a `Margin` of 0, and `Padding` set to 2,0,0,0.

The `Border` contains a `ContentPresenter` whose width is 29 units smaller than the `Border` that contains it.  The `Padding` on the `Border` would seem to account for 2 of the units.  Its `Margin` is 0 and it has no padding property.

I actually would like to make this window a bit narrower if I can without making the `Buttons` in the template any narrower.  Where is that 29 unit space coming from?  Is there any way to change its size?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you may have to set the ItemContainerStyle as show [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2924249/187697).

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this problem too in which I used a WrapPanel as the ListBox's ItemPanel, and i ended up with a gap between items in certain cases due to the problem you mentioned. Here is the fix:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
   </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```