# WPF ListBoxItem does not stretch to the maximum width

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF. I am trying to make the first column in the OrderItemsTmpl template to stretch to the maximum width that is available, but it does not work, the width only up to the width of the text inside. I don't want to use an absolute value. How to solve this ? Thanks

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="OrderItemsTmpl">
            <Grid Background="Brown" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=sItemName}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ></CheckBox>
                    <ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=aSinglOptns}"
                        Margin="20,0,0,0"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SinglOptnTmpl}"
                        Style="{StaticResource SheetListStyle}"
                        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}"
                 >

                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=fQty}"></TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>

<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>


<Style x:Key="SheetListStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Aqua"></Setter>

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                        <Border
                            CornerRadius="8"
                            BorderThickness="2">
                            <ScrollViewer>
                                <WrapPanel
                                    IsItemsHost="True"
                                    Orientation="Vertical"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

ListBox that content the item

```
<Grid Background="Pink" Grid.Row="1" >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=sDita}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" ></TextBlock>

                        <ListBox
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                Background="Aqua"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=aOrderItems}"
                                Name="OrderItems"
                                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource OrderItemsTmpl}"
                                Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                                ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}"
                                Style="{StaticResource SheetListStyle}">

                        </ListBox>
                    </Grid>
```

**UPDATE** 
I realized because of `<Style x:Key="SheetListStyle">`
I am using WrapPanel, it won't stretch to max width even you apply HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
I have to use other panel instead, but anybody know what could be used ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the `ListBox`'s control template. You're using a `WrapPanel` and you're aligning it to the left. Use a `StackPanel` and allow it to stretch (the default):

```
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                    <Border
                        CornerRadius="8"
                        BorderThickness="2">
                        <ScrollViewer>
                            <StackPanel
                                IsItemsHost="True"
                                Orientation="Vertical" />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

Alternatively, you could use the `ItemsPresenter` control instead of the panel directly. `ListBox` uses a `VirtualizingStackPanel` by default that would also give you virtualization (which you've disabled).

Answer (score 9):

There is a property on most collection controls that makes a whole row selectable and I suspect that you *might* need to have it set. If you haven't set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property to `Stretch`, then *that* is your problem.

Ahhh... I've *just* noticed that you *did* set this property.

Ok, let's have another go... I can see that you are using a `StackPanel` inside your `OrderItemsTmpl` `DataTemplate`. These controls don't have any effect on the `Width` of their children, so I think that *that* is your problem. Try changing it to another `Grid` control instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I have converted the stackpanel to grid, but still it does not work stretch to the maximum width.

Comment: Thanks. HorzontalContentAlignment="Stretch" is the answer that solved my problem.

Comment: oh my gosh! I can't believe I didn't think of this first.  Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838828/how-to-get-a-listbox-itemtemplate-to-stretch-horizontally-the-full-width-of-the)

I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I can't find a question with the same answer.

Add HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" to your ListBox. That should do the trick.

Comment: This is what helps me. Thanks!