# Conditional listbox background

Tags: wpf, listbox

I want to change the background of a listbox if one of the item contain "test"
You'll see a picture with multiple list box and I want to make the background in gray if item wording is "test" ( in the picture is "Férié")

How to do that simply ?

EDIT :

I don't want to change the content of an element. I want like the image
[image: template]

Comment: What precisely do you mean with "_background of the listbox element, **(not the item)**_"? (emphasis on the part in the parantheses). What do you consider listbox element, what do you consider item. Also, most parts of the item (whatever it is) are probably transparent, with the background color of the listbox/listbox element "shining through". Trying to give you suggestions requires to first have an understanding of what **exactly** you are trying to achieve here. Please do NOT explain here in the comments. Rather, **edit** and improve your question.

Comment: Edit done. You can see what I want in the image.

Comment: Are you trying to say, currently your item in the listbox only colors the background for the text, but not across the whole width of the item? If this is your problem, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838828/how-to-get-a-listbox-itemtemplate-to-stretch-horizontally-the-full-width-of-the (