# Why is binding a child element to parents ActualWidth Property making it too big?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a `ListBox` containing a DataTemplate, where I want to use a Dockpanel to let the last Child fill up the available space (Last Child in my case is the Textblock, which will be rendered in the center).

To do this, I have the following code (with additional DataTemplate on the ComboBox removed, since it isn't needed in the context of my question):

```
<ListBox x:Name="IsoLimitsList" ItemsSource="{Binding ISOLimits}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedISOLimit}" Margin="10, 0" BorderThickness="0" 
            Padding="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=IsoLimitsList}">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsActive}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>    
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.AllOxyColors, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" 
                            Width="150" DockPanel.Dock="Right" SelectedValue="{Binding Color, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValuePath="Value" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5, 2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This works perfectly fine, except that the Dockpanel is just a few pixels too big, resulting in a Scrollbar within the Listbox:

[image]

Question is: Where does the extra width come from? Can I remove the extra width without having to write another dataconverter?

What I have tried so far:

- Removed changed Padding/Margin values of all the elements, but they all work as expected.
- Give the ListBox a fixed Width instead letting it stretch within its parent. Doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: DockPanel will stretch on its own. Rather the ListBoxItem to Stretch using ItemContainerStyle. Avoid binding elements to parent dimensions. Rather make use of the natural sizing behavior of the panels.

Comment: Yep. Lose the actualwidth binding. Stretch the listboxitem content like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838828/how-to-get-a-listbox-itemtemplate-to-stretch-horizontally-the-full-width-of-the

Comment: Also. I've never been much of a fan of dockpanel. I prefer grid and columns. Make the columns fixed width or share max width and  * for the last one the combo.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestions, I'll give stretching the listbox via the itemcontainerstyle a try! :) The whole thing is a bit difficult, since this is just a part of a bigger GUI, where all sections are resizeable..

Comment: So I changed to using a `Grid` and set `HorizontalAlignment" of a style targeting `ListboxItem` to `Stretch` using `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` as you suggested. Works like a charm, thanks a bunch! If you want to add it as answer to the question, I'll gladly mark it :)