# Pivot item datatemplate

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, datatemplate

I want to fill my pivotpage using bindings following [this tutorial](http://babaandthepigman.wordpress.com/2010/09/20/data-binding-pivot-control-wp7-mvvm/). It works very well except for 1 fact. My content doesnt fill to it maximum potential.

**Normal:**

[image: normal button filling]

**XAML:**

```
<controls:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION">
    <!--Pivot item one-->
    <controls:PivotItem Header="item1">
        <Button Content="test" />
    </controls:PivotItem>

    <!--Pivot item two-->
    <controls:PivotItem Header="item2">
        <Grid/>
    </controls:PivotItem>
</controls:Pivot>
```

**With binding:**

[image: binding button filling]

**XAML:**

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TheShopApp.UI.ViewModels.TestPivotItemViewModel">
        <Button Content="Test" />
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

---

```
<controls:Pivot Title="{Binding Path=ApplicationName}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PivotItems}">
    <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="grid">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    Text="{Binding PivotTitle}"
                    d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <helpers:DataTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</controls:Pivot>
```

So now my question is: how can I get my binding content to look like the normal content? I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135375/how-do-i-make-a-wpf-data-template-fill-the-entire-width-of-the-listbox) which is sort of the same, but I couldn't figure out how too implement it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to add the following XAML to the templateselector: `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"`

**XAML:**

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TheShopApp.UI.ViewModels.TestPivotItemViewModel">
        <Button Content="Test" />
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

---

```
<controls:Pivot Title="{Binding Path=ApplicationName}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PivotItems}">
    <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="grid">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    Text="{Binding PivotTitle}"
                    d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <helpers:DataTemplateSelector HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</controls:Pivot>
```